# How to make a routine deal with observable collection of instances of a generic class

Tags: c#, reflection, observablecollection, generic-collections

I want to make a logger (in a library) that iterates through every field of whatever class and sets all values in a comma separated values line.
It's input value is a observable collection of whatever class. To make it generic I made it

ObservableCollection newObcObject.

```
public static bool WriteLog_Reflection(string fileName, long maxLogSizeMB, ObservableCollection<object>newObcObject, out string strError)
{
  try
  {
    strError = string.Empty;
    string lines = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in newObcObject)
    {
      foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
      {
        //string str = prop.Name + " = " + prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
        lines += prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString() + "; ";
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    strError = exc.ToString();
    return false;
  }
}
```

and this works..

The problem now is how to convert a specific observable collection to an object observable collection.

This is my solution but I'm open to whatever other solutions.
thanx

Comment: You really shouldn't write code with `catch (Exception exc)` in them. It's bad practice to catch a general exception. It'll just make your code more fragile.

Comment: @Enigmativity that is very interesting could you please elaborate it? Whatever exception will fall in the catch why would it make my code fragile?

Comment: Because if there is a bug that gets caught you aren't doing anything with it - the method returns and the calling code continues (possible now in a bad state). If you don't catch like that then you have a much better chance of writing code that doesn't throw errors in the first place, because you'll spot your errors sooner rather than later, thus making your code more robust. Catching every exception just hides errors.

Comment: Ok thanx for the explanation now that is much clearer so it's a matter of countermeasures. Fine I concur. But here it's a serialization s/r so it doesn't matter what happen if something goes wrong I just care about the fact that it hasn't serialized.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) using its [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method.
Since `ObservableCollection<>` implements `IEnumerable`, this works for it too.

```
var c = new ObservableCollection<int>();
ObservableCollection<object> oc = c.Cast<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since all you do with `newObcObject` are enumeration and reflection, you don't need it to be `ObservableCollection<T>`. Just make it [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (you event don't need its generic counterpart):

```
public static bool WriteLog_Reflection(string fileName, long maxLogSizeMB,
    IEnumerable newObcObject, out string strError)
{
    // ...
}
```

But generic method with `IEnumerable<T>` will allow to simplify code:

```
public static bool WriteLog_Reflection<T>(string fileName, long maxLogSizeMB,
    IEnumerable<T> newObcObject, out string strError)
{
    // ...
    // This:
    // 
    // string lines = string.Empty;
    // foreach (var item in newObcObject)
    // {
    //     foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    //     {
    //         lines += prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString() + "; ";
    //     }
    // }
    //
    // could be replaced to this:

    var lines = string.Join("; ", newObcObject
        .SelectMany(item => item.GetType().GetProperties(),
            (item, property) => property.GetValue(item, null)));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Very brilliant Dennis and nearly there. But there are two problems:

Comment: 1. each field of class has to be separated by a ; but each different instance of the class has to be separated by a new line. E.g. 1; "AAA";\n2; "BBB".

Comment: 2. how to do the other way round? That is the string above in an observable collection?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass ObservableCollection, since you use reflection IEnumerable is enough. Almost all collections implement IEnumerable (the non generic one!):

```
public static bool WriteLog_Reflection(string fileName, long maxLogSizeMB, IEnumerable newObcObject, out string strError)
{
    try
    {
        strError = string.Empty;
        string lines = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in newObcObject)
        {
            foreach (var prop in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                //string str = prop.Name + " = " + prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
                lines += prop.GetValue(item, null).ToString() + "; ";
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        strError = exc.ToString();
        return false;
    }
}
```